# Reducible polynomial must have a factor of degree at most $n/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Let $f \in F[x]$ with $F$ being a field. Prove that if $f$ is reducible then it must have a factor of degree at most $n/2$, where $n\ge 2$ is the degree of $f$.

My attempt: For the integral domain in particular the field $F$ we have the degree formula $\deg (g_1g_2) = \deg(g_1) + \deg(g_2)$ holds for $g_i \in F[x]$, therefore if $f$ is irreducible it must factor into two non constant polynomial such that $$f = g_1g_2$$ with $\deg(g_i)\ge 1$. If both $g_i$ factor has $\deg > n/2$ then the sum of the degree will greater than $n$. Contradiction. Is my proof correct?

Comment: yes indeed correct